# Neo4j: How do you use datetime property range to statement to query last 15 minutes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with email data and would like to use an existing query and add to it.  I would like to add `and where lastseen(which is stored as DateTime) within the last 15 minutes`, without typing in the full datetime range in the cypher statement.  Something like (lastseen - (datetime() - 15MM)).

Below is a sample `Sender` nodes properties:

```
<id>:12662  domain:corp.com  firstseen:"2020-01-14T06:02:33Z"  lastseen:"2020-01-14T06:25:45Z" name:person@corp.com  timesseen:300
```

The following is the query I would like to incorporate the time portion in:

```
MATCH path = (s:Sender)-->(a:Attachment)-->(:Recipient)
WITH s, COUNT(DISTINCT a) AS cnt, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE cnt >= 2
return paths
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `duration` function to get your range.

The duration mask `PT900S` is 900 seconds.

```
WITH datetime() AS end 
WITH end, end - duration("PT900S") AS start
RETURN start, end, duration.between(end, start)
```

Incorporated in your query it might look something like this...

```
MATCH path = (s:Sender)-->(a:Attachment)-->(:Recipient)
WHERE datetime() - duration("PT900S") <= s.lastseen <= datetime()
WITH s, COUNT(DISTINCT a) AS cnt, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE cnt >= 2
RETURN paths
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you @Dave Bennett

Comment: Where can I find more info on the PT900S part.  I can see that it is 900 seconds, but is there documentation somewhere on this? @Dave Bennet

Comment: you bet - https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/functions/temporal/duration/